# What is the Laurent series for the given function?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we find a Laurent series for 
the function $$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$ in the region $1<|z|<\infty$? I can find for the region $|z| < \infty$ easily and in terms of powers of $z$. But the question I think is to find in powers of $z-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$|z|>1\implies\frac1{|z|}<1\implies \frac{z+1}{z-1}=\frac{z+1}z\frac1{1-\frac1z}=$$

$$=\frac{z+1}z\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{z^k}=\ldots$$

Comment: is it possible to find a Laurent series in power of z-1 here?

Comment: Of course, @sundaresh...but it is almost already given there: $$\frac{z+1}{z-1}=1+\frac2{z-1}\ldots\;\text{and voila!}$$

Comment: that's great...I was stupid enough to have not guessed it myself.